# Linear Independence of $v$, $Av$, and $A^2v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a 3x3 matrix and $ v \in \Re^3 $ with $ A^3v = 0 $ but $ A^2v \neq 0 $.
Show that the vectors $ v, Av $ and $ A^2v $ are linearly independent.
(From Alan MacDonald's Linear and Geometric Algebra, Problem 3.1.5).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am also trying to understand this geometrically- If multiplication by A is to be thought of as a rotation + length dilation, is there any special significance to the fact that this operation, when repeated 3 times, yields a zero vector?

Comment: @user997712 I amended my answer to address the geometric aspect - mainly to make the response worthy of your upvote.

Comment: Unfortunately, this geometric interpretation doesn't fit this matrix $A$ at all. Only matrices with complex eigenvalues will do as you say, and only on certain subspaces. I suspect you don't know about eigenvalues/eigenvectors yet, but this matrix $A$ has only one eigenvector ($A^2v$) and $0$ is the only eigenvalue. In appropriate coordinates, it sends the $x$-axis to the $y$-axis, the $y$-axis to the $z$-axis, and collapses the $z$-axis to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might try to see what would happen if they were linearly *dependent*?

Certainly, you could write an equation down from that assumption.  That equation would involve a linear combination and, once you've got a linear combination, you can multiply through by $A^2$ to get the result.

**Edit**

Per your request, here's a more geometric way to think of it.

First, $v$ cannot be an eigenvector of $A$.  (Can you see why?)  Thus, $v$ and $Av$ together span a 2D subspace, say $S$, of $\mathbb R^3$.

Next, we need to show that $A^2v$ does not lie in $S$.  Well, to say that $A^3v=0$, while $A^2v\neq 0$ is to say that $A^2 v$ lies in the null space of $A$. Thus, if $A^2v$ did lie in $S$, there would be some linear combination of $v$ and $Av$ that lied in the null-space of $A$.  But since $Av$ already maps to the null-space under application of $A$, we would get that $v$ must also map to the null-space of $A$, which is a contradiction.

More generally, you might think of multiplication by $A$ as folding up space, even in higher dimensions.  Multiplication by $A$ once sends the one-dimensional null-space to zero and something also maps to that null-space.  Multiplication again does it, well, again.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: write down the equation : $a_1v+a_2Av+a_3A^2v=0$  .Now the idea is to  multiply $A$ on both sides. What must the coefficient $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be if you multiply several times $A$ on both sides?